# ClaimsIdentity not working properly in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, claims-based-identity

I want to authorize user in WebApi using ClaimsIdentity. In my AccountController which inherits ApiController class I have my two methods to test user authentication. One is a proper method used to receive user's data from other app based on his AD name and authenticates him saving his data as a Claim. The other one is a test method which I call after the previous one to check if the user is authenticated and has claims set.
Unfortunately the login method doesn't seem to set his Identity correctly even though the cookie is generated. The second method than works as if the user wasn't even authenticated and doesn't have any claims.
I have tried some various combination of creating his Identity but nothing seems to work.
Maybe you can see what I am missing.

AccountController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("account/login/{userActDirName}/{realmId}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(string userActDirName, long realmId)
        {
                //getting user data
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(userActDirName, "1");
                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = userActDirName };
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "1");

                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ...
                    }

                    user = await UserManager.FindAsync(userActDirName, "1");
                }
                Authentication.SignOut();

                ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                cookieIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userActDirName));
                cookieIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("User", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData)));

                
                Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, cookieIdentity);
        }

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
        {
            get { return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
        }
        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
```

IdentityConfig.cs

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = false
            };
            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = -1,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = false,
                RequireLowercase = false,
                RequireUppercase = false,
            };
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Api.Startup))]

namespace Api
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the string "User" while creating claim for complete user object as JSON, using the following code :

```
cookieIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("User", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData)));
```

Therefore when checking if the user is authenticated or not, use the follwoing code to check if the above mentioned claim exists or not. It will also give you full JSON that you stored while adding "User" Claim.

Remember the type casting below is very important
also use the following namespace

```
using System.Security.Claims;
```

before using the following code

```
var user = "";
var claims = 
((ClaimsIdentity)filterContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity).Claims;
                    
foreach (var c in claims)
{
    if (c.Type == "User")
         user = c.Value;
}
```

I have used this code in a custom "AuthorizationFilterAttribute". Therefore I have

> filterContext object

you can get

> RequestContext object

easily in any WebAPI-Method e.g.

```
        this.RequestContext.Principal.Identity
```

therefore,

```
var claims = 
    ((ClaimsIdentity)this.RequestContext.Principal.Identity).Claims;
```

will work in any web api controller.

Comment: this.RequestContext.Principal.Identity
will work any where in ApiController based Controller